# when i run enzyme example, i got "SyntaxError: /Users/a2014/Desktop/draghtml/test/test.js: Unexpected token (58:26)"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mocha.js, enzyme

this is my test code

```js
import React from 'react';
import { expect } from 'chai';
import { mount, shallow } from 'enzyme';
import Welcome from '../script/src/entry';

describe('<Welcome />', () => {
  it('calls componentDidMount', () => {
    const wrapper = mount(<Welcome />);
    expect(Welcome.prototype.componentDidMount.calledOnce).to.equal(true);
  });
});
```

this is my package.json

```js
  "scripts": {
    "cover": "istanbul cover _mocha -- --delay",
    "test": "mocha --compilers js:babel-core/register --require ./test/test.js",
    "dev": "webpack"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-cli": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-core": "^6.25.0",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.1",
    "babel-plugin-transform-runtime": "^6.23.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-stage-0": "^6.24.1",
    "chai": "^4.1.1",
    "enzyme": "^2.9.1",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^2.30.1",
    "isparta-loader": "^2.0.0",
    "istanbul": "^0.4.5",
    "jsx-loader": "^0.13.2",
    "karma": "^1.7.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage": "^1.1.1",
    "karma-firefox-launcher": "^1.0.1",
    "karma-mocha": "^1.3.0",
    "karma-phantomjs-launcher": "^1.0.4",
    "karma-spec-reporter": "0.0.31",
    "karma-webpack": "^2.0.4",
    "mocha": "^3.5.0",
    "phantomjs-polyfill": "0.0.2",
    "react-addons-test-utils": "^15.6.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "^15.6.1",
    "should": "^11.2.1",
    "webpack": "^3.4.1"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "babel-runtime": "^6.25.0",
    "react": "^15.6.1",
    "react-dom": "^15.6.1"
  }
```

when i run "npm run test",it got an error,how to solve it?

`SyntaxError: /Users/a2014/Desktop/draghtml/test/test.js: Unexpected token (58:26)`

`58:    const wrapper = mount(<Welcome />);`

it seems like dont't resolve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use Babel with a correct preset to parse the JSX syntax of your component, which is not supported by NodeJS, event in the latest version, and it will probably won't be supported in the future.

One option is to install the [React preset](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/preset-react/) and include it in a `.babelrc` file:

```
{
  "presets": ["react"]
}
```

Comment: i create .babelrc like this {
  "presets": ["react", "stage-0", "es2015"]
},    and "npm run test", It got an error "discribe is not defined",but i install macha,how to solve it

Comment: Did you install these presets? You need to do: `npm i --save-dev babel-preset-react babel-preset-stage-0 babel-preset-es2015`. Then run mocha with the command you have in `package.json`, `npm test`. If you have an example somewhere (e.g. GitHub) I could take a look

Comment: You have several errors: First, remove `--require` from the `"test"` script in the `package.json` file. Then change `enzyme.mount(` to just `mount(`. Then enzyme will complain about not having a document loaded. Finally you will have to follow these steps: https://github.com/airbnb/enzyme/blob/master/docs/guides/jsdom.md#using-enzyme-with-jsdom . I strongly recommend using jest instead of mocha, it will make you testing easier with enzyme.